# Use remove/hide instead of using split and join in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I would like to remove all £ symbols that appear on a webpage (.aspx page)

I am using the below jQuery;

```
$(':contains("£")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("£").join(""));
});
```

Split and Join works but it's causing some issue to the webpage (.aspx) styling. I am not sure what is causing the issue to styles.

So I would like to know, if I can use hide or remove to get rid of £ symbol on a webpage (.aspx) instead of Split and join?

All I am trying to achieve is to hide or remove £ symbol from the webpage (.aspx)

Please advise.

Comment: "Fix" the output of the server

Comment: It's a .net framework and I don't have access to backend. I can only add JQuery to make front end changes. So, that's the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` and `replace` method like below:

```
$('table').html($('table').html().replace(new RegExp('£', 'g'), ''));
```

[**Online demo (fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/rauhd7fq/1/)

Comment: That doesn't work. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/iamkrishnam/bzbpj7y8/

Comment: I am using this 

$(':contains("£")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(new RegExp('£', 'g'), ''));
}); But this is somehow affecting the CSS styling. May be I need to check further.